# What's the difference between the following cmd scripts?

Tags: windows-7, script, cmd.exe

I've tried launching several programs through a batch file and encountered problems but that is in the past.

I'm relatively new to scripts and command lines and this would be my question:
What's the difference between the following cmd scripts?

This one is accepted

```
Start Chrome
```

(i'm guessing here that some installed programs are recognized by title, even though the dir is not where the chrome.exe is the program still launches, registry keys play a part in this?)

this one works also

```
cd "FOO_DIR"
start FOO.exe
```

however these don't

```
start "FOO_DIR\FOO.exe"
```

(opens a new window without launching FOO.exe)

```
start /B "FOO_DIR\FOO.exe"
```

(writes the copyright text again and does nothing else)

(OS Windows 7 x64)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Start Chrome
```

This one works, because Chrome's executable is located in a folder which is in the `PATH` environment variable. `start` looks for programs in all folders in that variable. The environment variable `PATHEXT` contains a list of file extensions to look for and as `.exe` is contained by default, you don't need to write `chrome.exe`.

---

```
start "FOO_DIR\FOO.exe"
```

This does not work, because `start` will use its first argument as the window title if it is quoted. So this will open a new CMD with `"FOO_DIR\FOO.exe"` as its title.

To circumvent this, you can simply add an empty title argument before your command:

```
start "" "FOO_DIR\FOO.exe"
```

Comment: Furthermore, AFAIR, the title is mandatory when launching executables with command-line switches

Comment: It's not that `start` expects a title as its first argument (otherwise `start chrome` wouldn't work), it's that *if* its first argument is quoted, it expects it to be a title.

Comment: @jamesdlin ah, the documentation on this is a bit vague, thanks. I edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `"title"` or at least `""` after `start` like this:

```
start "title" "FOO_DIR\FOO.exe"
```

or

```
start "title" /B  "FOO_DIR\FOO.exe"
```

The root cause of the problem is that first argument in "" quotes is interpreted as a `title` parameter for new `cmd` window.

Also it helps to look at the command reference [(link)](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Thanks, that clarified the difference. And with the first one i think that "Non-executable files may be invoked through their file association just by typing the name of the file as a command." is the reason why just the name is enough... (not sure though)

Comment: If you are talking about your firts example with `start chrome`
I believe that calling chrome works, because it is has an entry in registry somewhere here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
If you look for chrome.exe you will most likely find the entry containing full path to executable.